# How to get all the images posted in a single story on Facebook through graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all the pictures and their engagements(comments or likes) that are posted together as a single page story. When I send a get request with the node being the page id and with parameter "field" the response that is get is:-

```
{
      "id": "some_id", 
      "from": {
        "category": "Tv show", 
        "name": "some_name", 
        "id": "some_id"
      }, 
      "message": "post with three photos", 
      "picture": "some_url", 
      "link": "some_link", 
      "icon": "some_link", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "some_link"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "some_link"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "value": ""
      }, 
      "type": "photo", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "object_id": "some_object_id", 
      "created_time": "2014-02-04T15:12:37+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-02-04T15:54:12+0000", 
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "some_id", 
            "from": {
              "category": "Tv show", 
              "name": "some_name", 
              "id": "some__id"
            }, 
            "message": "commen ton photo story", 
            "can_remove": false, 
            "created_time": "2014-02-04T15:54:12+0000", 
            "like_count": 0, 
            "user_likes": false
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MQ==", 
            "before": "MQ=="
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

In this post, I posted 3 photos together. But there is no information given to me from which I can get all the three photos through graph api calls. The object_id given to me is of the cover photo of the 3 images and is of a single image.

When I send a get request to the object_id, the response that I get is:-

```
{
  "id": "some_id", 
  "created_time": "2014-02-04T15:12:38+0000", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Tv show", 
    "name": "some_name", 
    "id": "some_id"
  }, 
  "height": 240, 
  "icon": "some_link", 
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 240, 
      "source": "some_link", 
      "width": 240
    }, 
    {
      "height": 130, 
      "source": "some_link", 
      "width": 130
    }, 
    {
      "height": 225, 
      "source": "some_link", 
      "width": 225
    }
  ], 
  "link": "some_link", 
  "picture": "some_link", 
  "source": "some_link", 
  "updated_time": "2014-02-04T15:12:38+0000", 
  "width": 240
}
```

The link that is received is the url of the same image not of the 3 images.

Comment: I need to do this through graph api only, no fql.

Comment: _“In this post, I posted 3 photos together”_ – and how did you do that?

Comment: We can select multiple photos while updating a status.

Comment: @keepitreal I don't remember correctly. I moved on. But most probably (95%) I did not.